# IndexOf and \ character

Tags: c#, format, substring

I'm having an issue trying to find the `\` character in some `string`.

I have a `string` like this

```
01-TN070340000000CHEXBSPT\nTapón Galvanizado Ø3/4\" Cabeza Hexagonal. Rosca BSPT
01-TN071000000000CHEXBSPT\nTapón Galvanizado Ø1\" Cabeza Hexagonal. Rosca BSPT"
05-CBPA0010002000-002\nConjunto Aislador BT 2000. Cerámica Blanca Pasante 1 Kv. 2000A. Genérico. Ferretería Estañada.
```

And all what i need is cut the string to get the string part before the `\n` but the thing is `IndexOf()` always returns `-1`.

Next, I tried the following:

```
int index;
string Articulo = "01-TN070340000000CHEXBSPT\nTapón Galvanizado Ø3/4\" Cabeza Hexagonal. Rosca BSPT";
index = Articulo.indexOf('\\'); // -1
index = Articulo.indexOf("\\n"); // -1
index = Articulo.indexOf(@"\n"); // -1
```

How am I supposed to get the start position of a substring that contains `\` character?

Comment: just use IndexOf('\n') because \n is like a char

Comment: @Shmosi thanks so much, i doesnt know that was like a char, should i delete the question? or it could be usefull for somebody ?

Comment: @JuanSalvadorPortugal leave it, maybe someone else is going to Need it :)                  I post my comment as an answer,  pleaase accept it

Comment: @Shmosi of course! ty again

Comment: Thats what we are all here for :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `.IndexOf('\n')` because `\n` is handled as one char.

One of your problems was to use `@` which made the outcome not newline, but `\n` as two chars, same with `\\`.

That is also the reason you can't find just `\` in your string, because it goes hand in hand with the `n`.